# The string return from markdown can't work if I insert into a HTML?

Tags: python, flask, markdown

I'm learning the flask web-framework. And encounter this problem.
I get some text from user in markdown style, and then transfer it into HTML and store in the database.

```py
title = request.form.get('title')
content = request.form.get('content')
html = markdown(content)
newPost = Article(title, html)
db.session.add(newPost)
db.session.commit()
```

When I extract the title and content from database and insert it into HTML directly, seems didn't work.

```py
#view.py
articles = Article.query.all()
print(articles[0].body) # <h3>Test</h3>
```

```html
<div class="container mb-5">
    <span class="row">
        <h4>{{ articles[0].title }}</h4>
    </span>
    <span class="row mt-3 mb-3">
        <span class="mr-2"><time>{{ articles[0].pub_date.strftime('%B %d %Y') }}</time></span>
    </span>
    <div class="row">
        {{ articles[0].body }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And I copy that element from chrome developer tool, the body string actually is:

```
<div class="row">
    &lt;h3&gt;Test&lt;/h3&gt;
</div>
```

Is that some thing related to encoding? And what should I do next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reason Flask/Jinja2 changes some chars in HTML but you can use `| safe` to inform Flask/Jinja2 that this text is safe and it doesn't have to change it

```
{{ articles[0].body | safe }}
```

Doc: [Jinja2: Working with Automatic Escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping)